# How to create a nxn Unity matrix in Armadillo?

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am trying to use Armadillo for C++. I am using the site for reference: [Armadillo Link](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#constants)

The simple and slow way I got it to work was:

```
arma::mat UnityMatrix = arma:mat(5,5,fill::zeros)
for (int ii = 0; ii < UnityMatrix.n_rows;ii++){
 for (int jj = 0; jj < UnityMatrix.n_cols;jj++){
   if (ii==jj){
     UnityMatrix(ii,jj)=1;
   }
 }
```

}
I create a matrix of zeros, and add ones on the diagonal. This works, but I am sure there is much more efficient way of doing this in Armadillo.

Armadillo has the umat type which should be unity, but I cannot figure out how to use it.

I tried:

```
arma::umat InitM;
InitM.set_size(5,5);
```

Which gave me a 5x5 matrix of random values.

When I tried other ways of initializing, but none would compile.

This seems so basic that I cannot find any online examples, but still cannot figure it out.

Comment: I figured out the answer right after posting. But that brings another question. What is the umat type I was trying to use and when would I use it?

Comment: To be clear, there is no such thing as a "unity" matrix. There is the [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix), which is sometimes known as a unit matrix. This is not to be confused with a [unitary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix), which is different to the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want an [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) and not a [unit matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones) from you first example. If you want the former than see the [`arma::eye<arma::umat>()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#eye_standalone) as suggested by Claes Rolen. For the latter, see you own reply.

As for the question in one of your comments, `umat` is a matrix with type [`uword`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#uword), i.e., unsigned int.

Answer (score 2):

I found it right after posting this question. The code is.

```
arma::mat UnityMatrix = arma:mat(5,5,fill::eye)
```

With fill::eye being the key. I finally found it when I searched for Identity matrix not Unity matrix.

Comment: One alternative is to use 'arma::mat UnityMatrix; UnityMatrix.eye(5,5);'